# How to pass an empty datetime to an mvc form with a [require] attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-core

I use a partial view of a **create form** in multiple page on my calendar system. On my home page everything is working properly without requiring anything. But on my other page, it need a model to be passed to it

```cs
 @await Html.PartialAsync("Create.cshtml", new Horraire {

    Jour = jourID,
    Semaine = semaine.GetValueOrDefault(),
    début = new DateTime(),
    fin = new DateTime()
});
```

The problem is, I have no idea on how to give it an **empty datetime** that doesn't break the input by adding milliseconds that the model doesn't accept

I tried to pass it a **null datetime**, but it's not accepted by the model due to the datetime being non nullable and required

```html
Working form
<input class="form-control" type="time" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Heure de Fin field is required." id="fin" name="fin" value="">

Problematic generated form
<input class="form-control" type="time" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Heure de Fin field is required." id="fin" name="fin" value="00:00:00.000">
```

I would like the form to work just like the other, and the value to truely be empty. This form need to be completed a lot of time and should be filled as fast as possible

Comment: *"it's not accepted by the model due to the datetime being non nullable and required"* - If it's required then it's required.  It sounds like you need to update the model to no longer require the value.

Comment: What happens if you set the value to 00:00:00

Comment: You could use a format string on the DateTime - ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

Comment: I mean, you have to give it two datetime otherwise the schedule won't make sense of it. The database requires it. But it should be empty in the form before you input it.

Comment: The basic format is a simple HH:mm but it doesn't seems to be taken by the partial view, eve when I try to force another default value in the form like value=""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DateTime` property needs to be nullable, even if it's required, i.e.:

```
public class Horraire
{
    ...

    [Required]
    public DateTime? fin { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the value will initially be blank on the form, but if the user fails to pick a date and time, then you'll still get a validation error.

Comment: If I do such a thing I can no longer use function like Substract, thus breaking my code appart

Comment: No, you just have to actually access the value, i.e. `fin.Value.Subtract`. You'll of course need to check that `fin.HasValue` to prevent `NullReferenceException`s if it happens to be null. Though, since it's required, it will not be null if `ModelState.IsValid` is true.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge of the .Value It work just fine now and I can null the Datetime.
The form is also working properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Nullable datetime which is specifically for null datetime purpose.

```
DateTime? nullableDateTime = null;
```

Comment: Additionally you can still tag a nullable with the `[Required]` data annotation.  The data annotation only fires when the model is ran through a validator.